# HTML: Checkbox input positioned to the left of a multi-line label

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to switch the position of label and input so that the checkbox renders to the left of the label.

```
<label>Question text</label>
<div class="input-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

For single lines of label text, this works fine:

```
.input-checkbox {display:inline; float:left; margin:2px 4px 4px 0;}
```

However, as you can see with multiple lines it wraps over top:
[image]

How can I style the label so that it stays to the right in multi-line situations? I do not want to change structure of the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I found that worked was to set both the `.input-checkbox` and the `label` to `display:inline-block;` and then set a `max-width` to the `label`  Just and example below.

```css
    .input-checkbox {display:inline-block; float: left; margin:2px 4px 4px 0;}
    .label-question {display: inline-block; max-width:90%;}
```

```html
<label class="label-question">Mentitum et tamen incididunt, minim arbitror eruditionem ab expetendis et elit 
    laboris iis magna consectetur iudicem tamen tempor aut a nisi a illum iis 
    pariatur a dolor nostrud, noster incididunt domesticarum et ita ipsum multos 
    aute laborum. Se ingeniis est arbitror. Pariatur quis an incurreret adipisicing 
    ad elit possumus sed aute quae hic e incurreret ad pariatur, fore nescius sed 
    possumus, ita veniam possumus id de sunt pariatur ea eram mentitum cernantur, o 
    ita transferrem. Velit occaecat do enim nulla, sed qui transferrem. Hic o dolore 
    amet duis. Ipsum non de quem nostrud. Offendit graviterque ab quibusdam, quis 
    proident non philosophari.</label>
<div class="input-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style> 
  label {position:absolute; padding-left:30px}
</style>
```

gives me this:

[image: result screenshot]

be happy to elaborate ...